# How to use the return from a static method in an "if statement" for redirection

Tags: java, android, android-intent, static-methods

This method retrieves a result which is an I or an R.

I want to redirect to different pages depending on what the result is.

***Problem is getApplicaitonContext() cannot be used in static methods.***

How do I get around this?

```
public static void receiveResults2(String result3) {
    System.out.println("this had better have the users tickets"+result3);
    String usersXML2 = result3;
    if (usersXML2 == "I"){
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewIncident.class);
             startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (usersXML2 == "R"){
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ViewRequest.class)
             startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Pass `Context` as an argument to `receiveResults2` method

Comment: use `.equals()` instead of `==`

Answer (score 3):

You can pass the context as a parameter to the static method.

You should also fix your String comparison (use equals and not ==).

Answer (score 0):

Though you cannot use that in static method, pass that as a method parameter.

Not sure about the type of `getApplicationContext()`, assuming that to be `ApplicationContext`

```
public static void receiveResults2(ApplicationContext contx,String result3) {}
```

String comparison should be done using `.equals()` or .`equalsIgnoreCase()`